# Vue forEach in computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, nuxt.js, computed-properties

I am building a checkbox filter, which stores the clicked checkbox value in an array. After that, the computed data should update but I am always getting undefined.

The Data Structure:
Casino {
brand_tags {
Brand_Tag_Name
}
}

Computed:

```
computed: {
    filteredCasinos: function() {
      return this.casinos.forEach(casino => {
        return casino.brand_tags.filter(brandTag => {
          return this.filteredCategories.includes(brandTag.Brand_Tag_Name)
        })
      })
    }
},
```

HTML (But that is working fine, I guess)

```
        <label for="Featured">Featured Casinos
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="filteredCategories" value="Featured">
        </label>
        <label for="Featured">Big Brands
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="filteredCategories" value="Big Brand">
        </label>
        <label for="Featured">New Casinos
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="filteredCategories" value="New Casino">
        </label>
        <label for="Featured">Pay n Play
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="filteredCategories" value="Pay N Play">
        </label>
        <label for="Featured">Trusted Casinos
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="filteredCategories" value="Trusted Casino">
        </label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `return this.casinos.forEach` returns undefined.

```
{ filteredCasinos: function() {
return this.casinos.filter(casino => {
 return !!casino.brand_tags.find(brandTag => {
    return this.filteredCategories.includes(brandTag.Brand_Tag_Name)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: but it is also returning undefined when I am not returning the forEach. Or is there a better way to iterate through the brand_tags of the casinos?

Comment: If you are using computed value you need to return value. If you want to return array you can use map function.
`filteredCasinos: function() {
      return this.casinos.map(casino => {
        return casino.brand_tags.filter(brandTag => {
          return this.filteredCategories.includes(brandTag.Brand_Tag_Name)
        })
      })
    }
 `

Comment: That would only return all Casinos and they wont get filtered

Comment: I edited the post. I hope it solves your question :)